# RecycleView scroll issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have such a problem: my recyclerView items contains recyclerview and when I make a scroll they do not scroll synchronously. So how can I solve this problem ?

https://paste.kde.org/pg55xfxeu

https://paste.kde.org/pxzduwpij

Comment: https://paste.kde.org/pmsxanbwr

https://paste.kde.org/pv9z1na9n

https://paste.kde.org/pp4l0tfgt

https://paste.kde.org/p8s9g6y3p

https://paste.kde.org/pfmzo9cie

https://paste.kde.org/ps48ahpdp

https://paste.kde.org/prjnwfahw

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to understand.  If i assume you mean when you scroll the items get displaced, then set your layout width to wrap-content

Answer (score 0):

For me this doesnt look like normal behaviour. 
You should probably check if this also occurs on other devices.

Android has many different OS versions created by smartphone manufacturers.
Bugs can occur on some of this devices and not on others.

Comment: I have checked it on many devices , but bugs occur on all off theme.
is there any example that I can look and understand what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: In my opinion this is a pretty good example that shows how to use a RecyclerView with a custom adapter

Comment: Thank you Maxim Kopecki.